# Defining a variable correctly using sql

Tags: php, sql, database, variables

I am trying to define my variable $isadmin to use in my session but I continue to get the error 'Undefined variable: isadmin'

This is my code:

```
<?php 
session_start();
ini_set("error_reporting",E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set("display_errors",1);

if ($_POST['username'] != '' || $_POST['password'] != '')
{
include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/flourish/toinclude.php";
$mydb=new fDatabase("mssql", "finance","mytest","",61495);
$result = $mydb->query("SELECT * FROM person WHERE personname=%s AND password=%s", $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
$isadmin = $mydb->query("SELECT isadmin FROM person");
if($result->countReturnedRows() == 0)
{
    $badaccount = "Incorrect User Id or Password entered, please try again.";
}
else
{
    $fetchresult = $result->fetchRow();
    $userid = $fetchresult['username'];


    if($isadmin=='N' || $isadmin=='Y')//As you mention in the question 
            //That admin column of two value one is N and one is Y
     $_SESSION['admin']=$isadmin;
    header("location:mainpage.php");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: the same error is still returning, if it helps the column name in the database is called 'isadmin'

Comment: I am unsure what you mean but I am running php version 5.3.5

Comment: All questions and answers submitted to Stack Overflow are for the benefit of future readers.  So please don't vandalize your question after you get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add line

```
  $isadmin = $fetchresult['isadmin'];
  below
  $userid = $fetchresult['username'];
```

as you are not assigning the isadmin table value to the variable it remains undefined.

Comment: The same problem still persits, I have echoed the output of $isadmin but 'Notice: Undefined variable: isadmin' is being outputed